# Why is the limit $E \, (\exp(\ln(10)\Delta\!\lg E) - 1) \xrightarrow{\Delta\!\lg E \rightarrow 0} E \, (\ln(10)\Delta\!\lg E)$ and not zero?

Tags: limits

I've found the following limit

$$E \, (\exp(\ln(10)\Delta\!\lg E) - 1) \xrightarrow{\Delta\!\lg E \rightarrow 0} E \, (\ln(10)\Delta\!\lg E)$$

But this doesn't make any sense to me. In my opinion the limit should be zero here, since
$\exp(\ln(10) \cdot 0)-1=1-1$.

What am I missing here?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E(\ln(10)\Delta$lg E)$\longrightarrow 0$, it makes sense! Also it's better than $0$, because in fact it's a Taylor approximation of degree one, but $0$ is of degree zero, and so it gives a better estimate in a larger neighborhood.